# Is the Google Sign-In API free to use?

Tags: google-signin

I'm searching for a good way to make authentication on my own website.

Just wondering if the [Google Sign-In API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) is free to use or not. Are there differences to the Cloud Identity?

Comment: Did you mean *this* [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/) ?

Comment: exactly. I picked the wrong link. Is it free to use?

Comment: Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free or not, I would not recommend using [this API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/).
There is a red text on the top of the page that says:

> The Google+ Sign-in feature is fully deprecated and is being shut down
>   on March 7, 2019. This will be a progressive shutdown, with
>   intermittent failures starting as early as January 28, 2019.
>   Developers should migrate to the more comprehensive Google Sign-in
>   authentication system.
>
> Migration tips are available for Web and Android.

Also, I would recommend using [Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/).

As for the pricing: [pricing for Cloud Identity](https://cloud.google.com/iam/pricing) and [pricing for Identity for Customers and Partners](https://cloud.google.com/identity-cp/pricing)

Comment: Thanks! That was what I searched!